# highlight current page in pagination?

Tags: php, css, pagination

i seen so many tutorials but it didn't work .i am trying this thing from last 3 days, in the end i need you guys help me.i am beginner in php so please explain step by step .
hundred thanx in advanced....

here is my css code:

```
div.pagination 
{

width:625px;
clear:both;
padding:10px 0 10px 0;
margin:0px;
text-align:center;
float:left;
clear:both;
font-size:11px;

}

div.pagination a 
{

padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin-right: 2px;
border: 1px solid #52bfea;
text-decoration: none; 
color: #52bfea;

}
 div.pagination a.current

{
padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
margin-right: 2px;
border: 1px solid #52bfea;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #52bfea;
color: #FFF;

}

div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active

{
border:1px solid #52bfea;
color: #fff;
background-color: #52bfea;
}
```

here is my php code:

```
<div class="pagination">
<?php
if($pagination->total_pages() > 1)
{
?>  
<?php
if($pagination->has_previous_page())
{
?>
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $pagination->previous_page();?>"><< prev</a>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
for($i=1; $i <= $pagination->total_pages(); $i++)
{ 
$class = ($i==isset($_GET['page']))? 'current' : '';
?>
 <a class='<?php echo $class?>' href="test.php?page=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i?></a> 
<?php
 }
?>
<?php
 if($pagination->has_next_page())
 {
 ?>
 <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $pagination->next_page();?>"> next >></a>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 <?php
 }
 ?> 
 </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What happens with your code? It is suppose that .current style is being applied to the current pagination number. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't think so this code has any problem...

Comment: the problem is when i click on page 2..i want my page icon color change....

Comment: and current style is applied but it applied every where ...for example 1 2 3 these all goes current style..

Comment: you need to change the selected page color or current page color please tell me details and print the $_GET['page'] value. may be  the $i value and $_GET['page'] is same..

Comment: selected page.suppose this is my pagination 1 2 3 i select 2 then 2 color change..that's is i want

Comment: check the loop of the page may be issue in looping.......

Comment: problem is resolve ..thanx to everyone of you guys for helping me ....

Comment: problem is not perfectly resolve ..when we didn't select any page and we refresh the page it gives error [undefined index page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
$class = ($i==isset($_GET['page']))? 'current' : '';
```

with

```
$class = ($i==isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1)? 'current' : '';
```

Comment: problem is not perfectly resolve ..when we didn't select any page and we refresh the page it gives error [undefined index:page]

Comment: check your error warnings in php, or put a failsafe into the page.

Comment: guri i already tried this answere but it didn't work. but finally error is solved .i am able to did bcoz of you guys ..thnx  i am sharing a answere ..

Answer (score 3):

problem is now finally completely resolved .but page 1 is by default is selected.

```
 $pg_no = empty($_GET['page'])? '1' : $_GET['page'] ;
 $class = ($i==$pg_no)? 'current' : '';
```